# Pagination doesn‘t work with loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to implement pagination inside my theme. I want to use understrap theme pagination. So, I downloaded [this file](https://github.com/understrap/understrap/blob/master/inc/pagination.php), add require code inside my functions.php. Next I added code inside my loop and... it's not working. What's wrong with my code?

```
    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'cat' => '-6'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);  

    if ($query->have_posts()) : 
        while ($query->have_posts()) : 
            $query->the_post();
            $background = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'medium');

            $category = get_the_category();
            $category_class = $category[0]->slug;            
            ?>

            <div class="row news__item">
                <div class="col-md col-lg-4">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="post-listing__image <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {} else {echo "post-listing__image-default";}; ?>" style="background: url('<?php echo $background; ?>');"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md col-lg-8">
                    <div class="info-bar">
                        <span class="badge badge-pill mm-badge">dodano: <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
                        <span class="badge badge-pill mm-badge <?php echo $category_class; ?>"><?php the_category(' '); ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-mm btn-mm--green">Więcej</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata(); 
        else: 
        ?>

        <h5>Brak wyników spełniających kryteria wyszukiwania</h5>

        <?php
    endif;
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
        <!-- pagination here -->
        <?php mmtemplate_pagination(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `wp_reset_query()` instead of `wp_reset_postdata()` and add `<?php mmtemplate_pagination(); ?>` before `wp_reset_query()`

Comment: It doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issues with your WP query. Try this code instead and let me know.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'cat' => '-6'
);
$wp_query=new WP_Query($args);
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
        $background = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'medium');

        $category = get_the_category();
        $category_class = $category[0]->slug;            
        ?>

        <div class="row news__item">
            <div class="col-md col-lg-4">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="post-listing__image <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {} else {echo "post-listing__image-default";}; ?>" style="background: url('<?php echo $background; ?>');"></div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md col-lg-8">
                <div class="info-bar">
                    <span class="badge badge-pill mm-badge">dodano: <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
                    <span class="badge badge-pill mm-badge <?php echo $category_class; ?>"><?php the_category(' '); ?></span>
                </div>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-mm btn-mm--green">Więcej</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
            <!-- pagination here -->
            <?php mmtemplate_pagination(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    else: 
    ?>
    <h5>Brak wyników spełniających kryteria wyszukiwania</h5>
    <?php
endif;
?>
```

**UPDATE:**
You should not call the loop inside your 'template_part' file. It should be in the main file, see below code.

```
<section class="section post-listing">
    <div class="container">
        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 2,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'cat' => '-6'
        );
        $wp_query=new WP_Query($args);
        if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();

            get_template_part('template-parts/loop/loop', 'post-listing');

        endwhile;
        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md">
                <!-- pagination here -->
                <?php mmtemplate_pagination(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
        else: 
        ?>
        <h5>Brak wyników spełniających kryteria wyszukiwania</h5>
        <?php
    endif;
    ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. And I don't get any errors or something

Comment: I updated the whole code in the original answer. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: It's working but now page is extremaly slow and is loading over and over. It give me whole section as output so now I have quite looooong page :D

Comment: Would you mind posting the whole template code here?

Comment: I posted whole loop code. This is the whole code for page. I call for this loop by get_template_part

https://pastebin.com/Q3qthi3H

Comment: Still print me out whole sections. And why I shouldn't call loop inside template file?

Comment: I not meant to call the loop inside the template file but `template_part` file. You should not add the loop inside `template_part` file. Just add the loop to the main file as per the updated answer and remove the loop from the `template_part` file. If still not working, send me the code of 'post-listing' file.

Comment: Or remove `get_template_part('template-parts/loop/loop', 'post-listing');` and add the whole code as per my first answer in your main template file.

Comment: Yeah, done that. Pagination shows but it print me whole page code and loop it. So basically I have like 10 pages inside one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174948/discussion-between-mmpl1-and-outsource-wordpress).